# Unable to Set Suite Variable for multiple variables in robot framework using "AND" condition

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying Set Suite Variable for multiple variables in Robot Framework (RIDE tool, keyword driven) using "AND" condition, but not able to.

The below is my script:

```
 Set Suite Variable    ${username} AND    
 ${password} AND    
 ${URL} AND   
 ${Browser}
```

Error im facing:

> Invalid variable syntax '${username} AND'.

pip list:

```
robotframework                          3.1.2
[...]
selenium                                3.8.1
```

Do let me know if any missing from my end. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also note to use at least two spaces. Now you have only one.

Comment: @laurent, Hi, it worked, but ${username} is passed, now it is stuck in ${password}

Comment: Set Suite variable    @{username}
    ...    AND
    ${pass}
    ...    AND
    ${URL}
    ...    AND
    ${Browser}

Comment: Have you had a look at Resource and [Variable files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files)?

Answer (score 6):

You can only set one variable at a time. [Set suite variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) doesn't support AND.

Comment: oh ok! thank u! wish there could be another solution, so it doesn't look messy!

Comment: @HimaManae: you can write your own keyword. Or you can save all of your data to a single dictinoary rather than multiple scalar variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Set Suite Variable` does not support setting multiple variables at once but you still want to do it in a single line I would try with `Run Keywords` instead:

```
Run Keywords    Set Suite Variable    ${VAR1}    value1    AND    Set Suite Variable    ${VAR2}    value2
```

But probably the cleanest way would be to have a keyword where your variables are set

```
*** Keywords ***
Set Variables
    Set Suite Variable    ${VAR1}    value1
    Set Suite Variable    ${VAR2}    value2
```